# ggplot: Stacked Barplot - geom_text labels messy

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, stacked-chart, geom-text

I have grouped my data as desired and added up the quantities correctly.

Now I want to create a stacked bar plot in in which I would like to display the labels per Unit.

The summarized data looks like this:

[image]

To read it in R:

```
df <- structure(list(date = structure(c(17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 
17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 
17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 
17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 
17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 
17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 
17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 
17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 
17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 
17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 
17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 
17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 
17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 
17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 
17785, 17785, 17785, 17785), class = "Date"), hour = structure(c(5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L), .Label = c("00", 
"02", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", 
"17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22"), class = "factor"), lGroup = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 9L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
5L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 9L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("AHX", 
"A1", "A3", "B1", "C1", "C3", "E1", "E3", "E5", "Andere"), class = "factor"), 
    unit = structure(c(2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 
    6L, 8L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 
    5L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 
    9L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 
    6L, 8L, 9L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 9L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 
    3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 9L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
    3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 
    3L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 9L), .Label = c("Andere", 
    "Einzelartikel", "Bund", "BundGroesser6m", "EuroPal", "Pack", 
    "Verschlag", "Rinnentransportkasten", "Sack"), class = "factor"), 
    values = c(1, 1, 1, 7, 1, 2, 1, 1, 6, 3, 15, 1, 3, 3, 1, 
    2, 2, 1, 9, 14, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 11, 1, 4, 1, 1, 
    1, 6, 5, 2, 16, 1, 3, 3, 2, 11, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    4, 2, 17, 1, 2, 2, 3, 7, 5, 2, 3, 1, 8, 1, 32, 4, 2, 1, 6, 
    2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 5, 10, 33, 1, 9, 2, 2, 7, 2, 6, 
    2, 3, 10, 2, 13, 8, 24, 1, 2, 5, 1, 7, 1, 13, 1, 1, 3, 4, 
    3, 11, 7, 11, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 2, 1, 7, 1, 7, 3)), row.names = c(NA, 
-125L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), groups = structure(list(date = structure(c(17785, 17785, 17785, 
17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 
17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 
17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 
17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 
17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785, 17785), class = "Date"), 
    hour = structure(c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 
    7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
    11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
    13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L
    ), .Label = c("00", "02", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", 
    "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22"
    ), class = "factor"), lGroup = structure(c(3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
    3L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 3L, 6L, 9L, 3L, 6L, 9L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 5L, 
    6L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
    5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 3L, 6L, 9L, 3L), .Label = c("AHX", 
    "A1", "A3", "B1", "C1", "C3", "E1", "E3", "E5", "Andere"), class = "factor"), 
    .rows = list(1:4, 5L, 6L, 7:8, 9:12, 13L, 14:15, 16:17, 18:20, 
        21:23, 24:27, 28:30, 31L, 32:36, 37:41, 42L, 43:45, 46:49, 
        50L, 51:52, 53:58, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62:64, 65:68, 69L, 
        70L, 71:73, 74:75, 76:79, 80L, 81:85, 86:87, 88L, 89L, 
        90L, 91:95, 96:100, 101:102, 103L, 104:107, 108:109, 
        110:115, 116:117, 118:121, 122:125)), row.names = c(NA, 
-47L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

for my stacked barplot i use (among other things) this code:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = hour, y = values, fill = unit, label = values)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(stat = "identity", check_overlap = TRUE, hjust = -.2)
```

Which results in this:

[image]

Alternatively, I have already tried the following:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = hour, y = values, fill = unit, label = values)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = unit)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = values), position = position_stack(0.5))
```

which gives me an even worse result...
[image]

The result should look like this (here my polished plot manually filled with values for the larger units via powerpoint...)

[image]

Any suggestions on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 4):

You've to work before with your data a bit:

```
library(tidyverse) 
library(RColorBrewer) # optional to have the palette red-blue

df %>%
    # group them
    group_by(hour, unit) %>%
    # summarise
    summarise(values = sum(values)) %>%
  ggplot( aes(x = hour, y = values, fill = unit, label = values)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")  +
  geom_text(size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))+
  # here the option for the blue-red palette and light background
  scale_fill_manual(values = colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(11,"RdBu"))(8)) + theme_light() +
  # this is going to put the legend at the bottom
  theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.box = "horizontal") +
  # this is going to change the title legend, hoping not have made any mistake!
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Lagereinheiten"))
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, I'll have to group it up again and sum it up. Make sense, thank you!